# How to Reposition the Footnote Mark?

Tags: footnotes

I often use the \footnote command and most of the time, I am satisfied where the footnote mark and adjoined footnote appears at the bottom of the page.

However, there are times when I would like to reposition where the footnote mark appears; for instance, to have it occur with no indentation (i.e., ``flushleft'') or to have it appear farther to the right than it is commonly placed.

Is there are way to do this? Thank you.